# Create method accessed from different view modal popup in MVC

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

I would like to ask a question regarding create method from a controller in MVC. I to call CreateView from another one and to display it in a Modal PopUp. My problem is that I managed to call the view in a modal, as I wished but the create action, does not add any record to the database, and update the table which displays those record from DB. Both views which I am using has a common controller, on index action, record are displayed in a table, this part work fine, but Create action, calls its CreateView but database is not updated and Index view also. I tried to use RenderPartial,Partial,Action,PartialAction and others but I only manage to get the view I want, but with out its functionality.I any one can tell me what I am doing wrong, I would appreciate that. Thank you very much in advance.
**Here is the code for Index View and where I want to call it with PartialAction at the bottom in a modal popup body**

```
   <div id="myModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div class="modal-dialog">

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                @{Html.RenderAction("Create", "All_beacons_", new Warden_MVC.Models.all_beacons());}

            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Here I have Create View I want to call(I want to mention that I tried to do the same thing without bootstrap styling, still did not work for me)

```
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<title>Create</title>


<script src="~/Scripts/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js"></script>
<script src="~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js"></script>q
@using (Html.BeginForm())
        {
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    <div class="panel-info">
        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3>Create New Unit</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="panel-body">

            <div class="form-horizontal">
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })


                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.x, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.x, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.x, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.y, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.y, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.y, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.comments, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.comments, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.comments, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.last_seen, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.last_seen, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.last_seen, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(model => model.neighbourID, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.EditorFor(model => model.neighbourID, new { htmlAttributes = new { @class = "form-control" } })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.neighbourID, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>

                <div class="form-group">
                    <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
                        <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>


            <div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-info">@Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")</button>

            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
}
```

and here I have the code for the controller which is common for both views

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Warden_MVC.Models;

namespace Warden_MVC.Controllers
{
public class All_beacons_Controller : Controller
{
    // GET: All_beacons_
    public ActionResult Index()
    {
        List<all_beacons> all_beacons_list = new List<all_beacons>();
        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {
            all_beacons_list = wardenEntity.all_beacons.ToList<all_beacons>();
        }
        return View(all_beacons_list);
    }

    // GET: All_beacons_/Details/5
    public ActionResult Details(int id)
    {
        all_beacons all_beacons_model = new all_beacons();
        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {
            all_beacons_model = wardenEntity.all_beacons.Where(x => x.idb == id).FirstOrDefault();
        }
        return View(all_beacons_model);
    }

    // GET: All_beacons_/Create
    public ActionResult Create()
    {
        return View();
    }

    // POST: All_beacons_/Create

    [HttpPost]
    [Authorize, AcceptVerbs(HttpVerbs.Post)]
    [ActionName ("Createb")]
    public ActionResult Create(all_beacons all_beacons_model)
    {
        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {

            wardenEntity.all_beacons.Add(all_beacons_model);
            wardenEntity.SaveChanges();
        }
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }

    // GET: All_beacons_/Edit/5
    public ActionResult Edit(int id)
    {
        all_beacons all_beacons_model = new all_beacons();
        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {
            all_beacons_model = wardenEntity.all_beacons.Where(x => x.idb == id).FirstOrDefault();

        }
        return View(all_beacons_model);
    }

    // POST: All_beacons_/Edit/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Edit(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add update logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }

    // GET: All_beacons_/Delete/5

    public ActionResult Delete(int id)
    {
        all_beacons all_beacons_model = new all_beacons();

        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {
            all_beacons_model = wardenEntity.all_beacons.Where(x => x.idb == 
id).FirstOrDefault();
            wardenEntity.Entry<all_beacons>(all_beacons_model).State = 
EntityState.Modified;
            wardenEntity.Entry<active_beacons>
(all_beacons_model.active_beacons).State = EntityState.Deleted;
            wardenEntity.SaveChanges();

        }

        return  RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
    public ActionResult getall()
    {

        List<all_beacons> all_beacons_list = new List<all_beacons>();
        using (wardenEntities wardenEntity = new wardenEntities())
        {
            all_beacons_list = wardenEntity.all_beacons.ToList<all_beacons>
();
        }
        return View(all_beacons_list);
}

    // POST: All_beacons_/Delete/5
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id, FormCollection collection)
    {
        try
        {
            // TODO: Add delete logic here

            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }
        catch
        {
            return View();
        }
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `[ActionName ("Createb")]` ? Remove it, otherwise specify the `action` and `controller` on your `@Html.BeginForm()`

Comment: I removed those but now I get
 System.Web.HttpException: 'Error executing child request for handler 'System.Web.Mvc.HttpHandlerUtil+ServerExecuteHttpHandlerAsyncWrapper
InvalidOperationException: Child actions are not allowed to perform redirect actions. , even if I added [ChildActionOnly] to my method in controller

Comment: Something is wrong with your view, you may have to dig deeper into the inner exception to find out. My guess is that the `Model` passed in is not the same type it's expecting.

Comment: I managed somehow to make the Create view, add the record to the database, but instead of rerouting to the Index View it throws me the same error in the comment above, before updating the Index view, but when I rerun the project, the record will be displayed. And it happens in both casses, with or without Model parrameter passed